# Why does T[number] not also return undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have a type as follows:

```
type GetUnion<T extends any[]> = T[number];
type Foo = GetUnion<[1, 2]>;  // 1 | 2
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwFUB2BLA9kgPAFShAHsBEgCYDOUAhkiANoC6AfFALxTa1ICuAtgEYQATvQDcAKFCQoAMTRpWseMnRZaARgA0UAExMRUKAHpDOqAB8oasQeNQAegH4xQA)

I know that "number" type represents union of all possible numbers, so `T[number]` should be like `T[0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ...]` which should be `T[0] | T[1] | T[2] | T[3] | ...` which is `1 | 2 | undefined`. But then why is the actual value only `1 | 2` and not `1 | 2 |undefined`?

Comment: @jcalz I assumed it would be that, but still seems to be `2 | 1` with the flag set: https://tsplay.dev/WyVbdw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[1, 2]` are subtypes of [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) and therefore have numeric [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) corresponding to the element type of the array.  That is, [the `Array<T>` declaration includes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1485)

```
interface Array<T> {
  [n: number]: T 
}
```

Note that this is `T` and not `T | undefined`, even though when you read from an arbitrary numeric index of an array you are quite likely to get an `undefined` result.  And when you use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like `Array<T>[number]`, you get the property type `T` out, not `T | undefined`.

This behavior pre-dates the existence of [null/undefined checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#null--and-undefined-aware-types).  As soon as you could expect `| undefined` to appear on possibly-undefined types, people started requesting that index signatures do this, and [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) gained a lot of community support.  But the TypeScript team [has always been skeptical](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-286592106) that this would actually be desirable.  Forcing people to check for `undefined` for index signatures would make a lot of idiomatic JavaScript fail to compile. Still, it was quite popular, so eventually [a `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) was introduced to make it so that when you read from a type with an index signature, you must check for `undefined`. This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#39560](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39560), where it is explained that:

- they still don't think that people will want this enabled by default, so it's not part of [the "standard" `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), and
- that it only affects the types of *values*, not the indexed access type.  In particular:

> #### Design Point: What's the type of `T[number]` / `T[string]` ?
>
> A question when implementing this feature is given this type:
>
> ```
> type Q = (boolean[])[number];
> ```
>
> Should `Q` be `boolean` (the type that's legal to write to the array) or `boolean | undefined` (the type you'd get if you read from the array)?
>
> Inspecting this code:
>
> ```
> // N.B. not a good function signature; don't do this in real code
> function zzz<T extends unknown[]>(arr: T, i: number): T[number] {
>     return arr[i];
> }
> ```
>
> It feels like the job of the checker in this mode is to say "`zzz` does a possibly out-of-bounds read and needs clarification". You could then write either of these instead:
>
> ```
> // Allows out-of-bounds access to silently occur
> function zzz1<T extends unknown[]>(arr: T, i: number): T[number] | undefined {
>     return arr[i];
> }
> // - or - 
> // Bounds checks for you
> function zzz2<T extends unknown[]>(arr: T, i: number): T[number] {
>     // TODO: Validate that 'i' is in bounds
>     return arr[i]!; // ! - safety not guaranteed but we tried
> }
> ```
>
> This has the *very* positive side effect that it means `T[number]` in a declaration file doesn't change meaning based on whether the flag is set, and maintains the identity that
>
> ```
> type A = { [n: number]: B }[number]
> // A === B
> ```

In short, they decided that they want `T[number]` to be the narrower *write* type of the index and not the wider *read* type, so that returning an actual value outside the bounds is of type `T[number] | undefined`, and so that declaration files and previously recognized type identities don't change.  Whether or not one agrees with those reasons, that seems to be the canonical answer for this question.